# Will separate high-pass filters work properly with two speakers wired in parallel?

Tags: speakers, high-pass-filter

[image]

I have wall-mounted satellite speakers – inexpensive Orbs are in one room and more expensive Gallo Divas are in an adjoining room. I need to wire these speakers in parallel with high-pass filters. The Orbs have a recommended cut-off of 150 Hz and the Divas have a recommended cut-off of around 80 or 100 Hz.

The one-channel diagram above shows what I believe are my two options: one filter or two per channel (the diagram is a single channel to keep it simple and save space).

Can I use a filter for each speaker with the appropriate cut-off as shown above in scenario A? Will the filters work properly if they are wired in parallel or will they somehow interact and create an odd second-order filter?

If that’s the case, am I limited to a single filter shown in scenario B? Obviously, it would be better if I could pair the more expensive speaker with the half-octave lower cut-off filter.

As the complete two-channel installation will be four 8 Ω speakers, I am assuming the effective impedance will be 4 Ω, and I have found 4 Ω high-pass filters. I understand the filters have to be at the proper impedance for the cut-off to operate at the desired frequency, so I don’t think impedance will be an issue regardless of whether I use scenario A or B because the impedance would be the same in either scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the effective output impedance of your amplifier.  In my experience audio amps tend to be designed to present a very low output impedance, as this increases efficiency and the issues of signal reflection that would be significant in RF don’t matter at audio frequency, rather the inertia of the speaker is better damped by a low-impedance amplifier.  In a scenario where the output impedance is close to zero (and at 100Hz I would expect an audio amp to approximate well to this) using two filters in parallel won’t be a problem.  If the impedance is significant though, you’ll find that in the band between the two cutoff frequencies, the speaker with the lower cutoff will receive more power, since the out-of-band filter will present a higher impedance.  Whether this would be noticeable is unclear and will depend on a number of external factors.